# Javascript Promise Variable Scope in For Loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, es6-promise

Newbie alert!

I'm trying to understand the variable scope for a promise inside a for loop.

Consider the following code:

```
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve =>
    setTimeout(resolve, ms)
  );
}

for (var i =0; i<4; i++){
  sleep(1000).then(() => console.log(i));
}
```

The promise is called 4 times at once and then responds with:

```
4
4
4
4
```

How can I keep reference to the i variable? In order to get

```
0
1
2
3
```

Or whatever execution order actually took place.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: The easiest solution is to replace `var` with `let`, but you should read up on why.

Comment: wow... Thanks... that did the trick. On my way to understand the differences.

Comment: Using let does cause the console to print the correct value but it does not give, what I expect to be, the intended performance: printing the value 1 second apart in incrementing values.

Comment: Simultaneous execution is fine... All I needed is the reference on what just got processed.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the `i` into the sleep function and resolve it.

```
 function sleep(i, ms) {
   return new Promise(resolve =>
     setTimeout(() => {
       return resolve(i);
     }, ms);
   );
 }

 for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
   sleep(i, 1000).then((data) => console.log(data));
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is just how you're calling your sleep function. You must use the `await` keyword inside of an `async` labeled function.

This should be how your code looks:

```js
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve =>
    setTimeout(resolve, ms)
  );
}

async function printSleep(){
for (var i =0; i<4; i++){
  await sleep(1000).then(() => console.log(i));
}
}

printSleep();
```

The key part you're missing is that you must use `await` to actually have your code wait for the sleep function to finish. If you don't it will queue the function and continuing executing the rest of the function in a synchronous fashion, causing your then statement to execute after the for loop has finished.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by [ASDFGerte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6692606/asdfgerte), by changing **var** to **let**, the i variable is kept within the block and outputs the desired reference.

```
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve =>
    setTimeout(resolve, ms)
  );
}

for (let i=0; i<4; i++){
  sleep(1000).then(() => console.log(i));
}
```